# How to identify data is Encoded using Server.UrlEncode() Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can we identify whether input data is Encoded using **Server.UrlEncode()** method or not?

I am looking for something like "**Server.IsUrlEncoded**"?

Answer (score 0):

This way you check also if url is **properly** encoded:

```
string url = "...";
if(Server.UrlEncode(Server.UrlDecode(url)) == url)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just decode and encode it regardless then you make sure it's encoded?